# Why am I getting "The ExternalInterface is not available in this container" in a Flex Mobile Project?

Tags: flexbuilder, flex4.5

I am using StageWebView to show a local HTML page (using file://). I want to call a function in my flex mobile project to be called from a JS function. Using ExternalInterface, I have

in Flex -
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFunction",myFunc);

in JS -

```
    function thisMovie(movieName) {
       if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
       } else {
         return document[movieName];
      }
    }

   function showAlert()
   {
    alert("Going to call AS function");
        thisMovie("ShowLocalHTML").myFunction("Hello");
    return false;
   }
```

I am getting "Error: Error #2067: The ExternalInterface is not available in this container. ExternalInterface requires Internet Explorer ActiveX, Firefox, Mozilla 1.7.5 and greater, or other browsers that support NPRuntime." when trying to run the application.

And my project targets Android platform. And  I have Mozilla, Chrome installed on my desktop - although I am not user if that is relevant to the problem.

Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am new to Flex and AS it took me a while to understand the problem. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html and http://sean.voisen.org/blog/2010/10/making-the-most-of-stagewebview/. What it means is External Interface is not available for use with StageWebView in AIR for android.

Answer (score 0):

True, but you still can communicate js <> air if you are using an ANE solution. Check here https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE I'm the coder of this ANE by the way! :)